# How to send JavaScript or Typescript object in HttpParams in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I would like to submit a complex model to my API. The model do contains objects and/or an array. Using `HttpParams`, I could submit simple `key, value` object as follows:

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
    .set('name','Foo')
    .set('birth','');
```

How to set a complex model? This didn't work!

```
var actionData = {
    model: { name:'Foo', birth:'2000-01-19 05:30:14T6' },
    filters: [ {key1:value1}, {key2:value2} ]
};

let httpParams = new HttpParams()
    .set('actionData', JSON.stringify(actionData));
```

Didn't work!

Comment: i tested your code and working fine

Comment: first of all how you can use this data please declare this data will use to backend or page navigation for use in params.

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor the model remains `null` into the server api.

Comment: Can you check whether your actionData object is as expected. JSON.stringify is a simple function takes object and turns it into a string. I am suspecting our server cannot parse object from string. One way to do that use a network tracker and look at the data you are sending to server

Comment: You submit a complex model using httpClient.post(url,yourModel). HttpParams only change the "url" as query, see https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo that was the solution. Please write this as answer so I accept it